# str_replace for multiple items then store results in new variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, str-replace

I have a string like this :

```
 $content = 'Hi @steve, have you seen what @dave wrote?';
```

I essentially want to locate only the words directly following the @ symbol (like twitter mentions), and then loop through each result performing a task with them.

I know how to strip the @ char from the entire string :

```
$strip_at = str_replace( '@', '', $content );
```

Which would result in $strip_at being :

```
Hi steve, have you seen what dave wrote?
```

But how would I use str_replace to locate each "mention", remove the @ symbol just leaving the word (a name in this case), and then store the results of each "mention" in an array to a new variable?

Desired result :

```
$mentions = array('steve','dave');
```

So I could then loop through $mentions and do stuff with the results, eg :

```
foreach ($mentions as $mention) {
   echo 'This persons name is '.$mention.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by means of a regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=@)(\w){1,15}/', $content, $results);
```

which will store this array in the variable `$results`:

```
[
     [
       "steve",
       "dave",
     ],
   ]
```

and you could enumerate the matches by looping over `$results[0]`:

```
foreach($results[0] as $name) {
  echo $name . '<br>';
}
```

prints:

```
steve
dave
```

If you're curious about what `/(?<=@)(\w){1,15}/` means:

`(?<=@)` - "lookbehind" - this means *we need a `@` to precede what we're actually interested in matching*

`(\w){1,15}` means *match a word with a maximum length of 15 (the max size of a twitter name)*

so together we're matching the twitter username that follows an @ sign.

Comment: So $results would be the variable I then loop through? $results as $result

Comment: @Grant you would loop over `$results[1]` like: `foreach($results[1] as $name) echo $name;`

Comment: ok that sounds perfect! Is there a way to do with without storing the original steve, dave objects (with the @ symbol) too as they will never been needed? So essentially I could use $results[0] instead of $results[1]

Comment: @Grant yes, see my edit post, you may use `preg_match_all('/(?<=@)(\w){1,15}/', $content, $results);`

Comment: Thank you so much, lastly with $results[10] you mean $results[0] right? Just checking?

Comment: Thanks again, not just for the answer but for the explanation too. If there was a bar in here I'd be buying you a drink right about now ;)